# The 4th in the trilogy

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, fun

I listened to Jeff saying that superuser.com is the 3rd in the trilogy. I guess that makes meta the 4th in the trilogy.

Do you remember that Douglas Adams continued to call his Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy a trilogy even after books 4 and 5?

Comment: It was always a "trilogy of four" even after he wrote the fifth book.

Comment: I try to pretend meta doesn't exist.

Comment: And yet you comment on it...

Comment: This question is meta to meta and doesn't belong here. It should be on meta.meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Actually the question is not meta to meta SO. It's meta to Hitchhiker's Guide... why this question is here I don't know.

Comment: @Jeff - you can try all you want, but we will always be here.  Waiting.  Breathing.  Whining.  In your dreams, you will hear us, and your days will be filled with the horror that awaits you in meta.

Comment: There is a **meta** for every site, it is silly to count them.

Comment: Per-site metas weren't introduced until well after this question was asked.

Comment: really? "put on hold" after almost 8 years? cmon guys, just leave things the way they are.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Do you remember that Douglas Adams
>   continued to call his Hitchhiker's
>   Guide to the Galaxy a trilogy even
>   after books 4 and 5?

Yes.

**edit:**

[image: The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy: A Trilogy in Four Parts]

Comment: I was going to say something smartass about you not answering the right part of the question until I re-read it and realized that you answered the only part of his post that -was- a question.

Comment: -1 because I don't remember it.

Answer (score 10):

IIRC on the fifth volume cover is written : "the fifth of the increasing inaccurately named HHGTTG trilogy".

Comment: YRC, or you and I are both on the same trip

Comment: That's the quote that I remember.

Answer (score 2):

This is more like [Dirk Gently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Gently).

Answer (score 2):

not to mention that instrumental on Rush's Counterparts that was Part 4 of the Gangster of Boats Trilogy

Comment: Strangely, it's also the _only_ song that's part of the Gangster of Boats trilogy.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the fourth in the trilogy, then who's the "JarJar" of metaSO? =)

Comment: I'll start this by saying...NOT IT!

Comment: http://www.ponyoverflow.com

Comment: I am Darth Vader for sure!

Comment: This would explain why, other than the pod racing, meta sucks so much.

Comment: I think I'm the Lobot of the trilogy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobot#L

Comment: But in that case, the fourth was actually first.

Answer (score 1):

Piers Anthony once mentioned that a trilogy is 27 books (3^3).

Needless to say, both Terry Pratchet's Discworld and Piers Anthony's Xanth are in their second "trilogy" using the above definition.

Comment: Gods.  I remember when Xanth was actually a trilogy.  3 books.  That was it.  This was also long enough ago that I thought they were pretty good, too.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents concerning HHGTTG: Parts 1 and 2 are awesome, part 3 is good, part 4 is bad, part 5 is awful. I hope that doesn't translate to the SO trilogy.