# What's a good way to refer to all four sites collectively?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stack-exchange-history

Now that Stack Overflow has become a group of four sites (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, and now this meta site), what's a good way to refer to the complete group? Is there an official name?

Comment: I have just realized how good this question is lol. It would be really nice to have official name, made by community :)

Comment: Related: *[Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)* (for instance, search for "Super User")

Answer (score 12):

The Trilogy. Obviously. After the many books in the Hitchhiker's Guide Trilogy.

Comment: Indeed the fourth book has the comment "The fourth book in the inaccurately named Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy Trilogy" and the fifth has "The fifth book in the increasingly inaccurately named..."

Comment: It doesn't seem fitting to refer to websites as a "trilogy", though.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to refer to the trilogy is, of course, with a regular expression:

```
S[OFU]
```

Pronounced "ess oh eff you", naturally.

Comment: I thought SOFU rhymes with tofu.

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it already called the [Stack Overflow Trilogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/849/the-4th-in-the-trilogy/859#859)?

But if an abbreviation is key, **SOFU** could work

Comment: SOFU? I think many people might mistake that as an abbreviation for something else.

Comment: Quadrology perhaps.

Comment: SOFU - and if you want to include Meta, then SOFUM.

Comment: Definitely this one (trilogy), ala Hitchhiker's Guide "trilogy"

Answer (score 5):

```
M?S[OFU]
```

because we *can* parse the trilogy with regex, even if it's made up of HTML.

Comment: This answer needs 3900 votes, NOW!

Answer (score 4):

- SO/SF/SU/Meta
- My addiction
- The Stack Overflow family

Answer (score 4):

The Super Stack Fault Tetralogy. (That's what I'm going to call it, anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

```
S*
```

or maybe

```
S?
```

I'd like to think that most of the users of these sites either already know what a wildcard is, or could be taught easily.

Comment: S? would seriously make the most sense... but no one would understand it and it would be confusing for SEO, etc.

Comment: S* would be more widely understood, if less accurate

Answer (score 2):

The Four Horsemen?
Stackapalooza?

Comment: I like Stackapalooza, if only as a joke.

Answer (score 1):

(The) [Stacks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5534/does-the-stack-overflow-software-have-a-name/5619#5619)

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow site family?

Stack Overflow is still the first site. The commercial version of this web application is called by it, so... there is also [so-family tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/so-family).

EDIT:

Stack Family?

Comment: Calling it the site family makes sense, however it's a bit long, and a bit clunky in some situations...

Answer (score 1):

Well, they call it the Stack Overflow Trilogy on the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/). But I have no idea how you'd include Meta in that group.

Comment: Meta is the redhead stepchild.

Comment: Some folks prefer red heads you know.

Answer (score 1):

The Atwoods Family (TAF, speak "tough")

Answer (score 1):

[The Increasingly Inaccurately Named StackOverflow Trilogy](http://www.amazon.com/Increasingly-Inaccurately-Named-Hitchhikers-Trilogy/lm/RYX5EQJ0M23VF)

Answer (score 1):

I call it simply **Jeff's** :)

**Meta User Super Server Stack Overflow Fault** when I want to explain it to my colleagues :)

Answer (score 0):

Stack-Tip Downwash

Only a suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

For me:

```
Stack Overflow is dev
Server Fault   is svr
Super User     is usr
Meta SO        is alt
```

and if you think about it, each of them are just variants of **CODEMONKEY**!!!

So I vote for **The CODEMONKEY COMMUNE**

Why *Commune*? I give you the top 3 results on Wikipedia's disambig page for *Commune*:

Commune may refer to:

- Commune (intentional community), a community in which resources are shared
- Commune (socialism), a leftist model for society
- Commune (card game), a poker-based bluffing game

Also if you haven't heard it yet, you may want to hear the [Code Monkey song](http://www.jonathancoulton.com/music/thingaweek/CodeMonkey.mp3) by [Jonathan Coulton](http://www.jonathancoulton.com/2006/04/14/thing-a-week-29-code-monkey/). Just don't go overboard and adopt it for an anthem or anything.

Answer (score -1):

3.1 (like 5.1 Surround Sound)