# What's the correct regular expression for SO SU SF?

Tags: discussion

Is it S[OUF]?

Just wondering

Comment: Doesn't this belong on SO?

Comment: For some reason, I wish they all spelled out STFU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Comment: oops I think I've just ruined you beautiful 404 rep number ( not found? )

Comment: now it's either a Nigerian scam or a dead body: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/419_(number)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you should specify begin and end with word boundaries, otherwise if someone curses:

```
SOD!
```

you might get an unintentional match.  So that gives us:

```
\bS[OFU]\b
```

We might also be interested in detecting things like `S.O.`.  But we don't want to pick up `S.O` -- that's just silly.  So we can introduce an optional . in a group, and then refer back to it:

```
\bS(?P<dot>\.?)[OFU](?P=dot)
```

At this point, things get a bit tricky, since we still want the trailing wordboundary, but only if we didn't match a dot (since \b won't match between a dot and a space, for instance).  Maybe a negative lookbehind..?  I'm open to assistance on this point.

Comment: who refers to it as S.O. ?

Comment: Me, as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are many possible ways to write it:

```
S[OUF]

S(?:O|U|F)

(?:SO|SU|SF)

(?:SO|S[UF])

(?:S[OF]|SU)

(?:SF|S[OU])
```

et.c...

(Notice that ?: makes a non-matching parenthesis so that it doesn't affect the result of the match.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking regular expression, then it has to be something like

```
 S(O|F|U)
```

where you're given a choice among the letters in the parentheses, but at least one is to be chosen at a time. Or streamlined to:

```
 S[OFU]
```

Which, as pointed out, matches up with one character. And the S is looking to join in on that bracket orgy.

Or this dupe: [What's a good way to refer to all four sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5924/whats-a-good-way-to-refer-to-all-four-sites-collectively/)

Comment: Nope. [OFU] matches exactly one character, it's not optional. Not to be confused with [O|F|U] that also matches the pipe character.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer plain old (SO|SU|SF|MSO).

A regex to match 4 possible sites is overkill if you ask me anyway.

Comment: Why even abbreviate Meta at all - you only save 1 character going from "Meta" to "MSO"

Comment: To save a character.`:)`

Comment: I just go with "meta".  It's as many keypresses as MSO and doesn't make me think of miso.