# Where can I ask questions about Google (search) ranking/list order?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about the ranking/list order in the results at Google. Where should I post my question?

Editor note: From [OP's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22112/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-google-search#comment45287_22113) to [one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22113/)

> Well i am developper and webmaster for that site. It was made for a customer. The customer asks me now, why -- while searching for the same phrase -- one day, his site is listed top 1 or 2, but the other day it is not listed at all. But if he searches for a slightly different phrase (namely plural instead of singular), the website is found and listed top 5. Then, after a few days, the site is back number 1 with the original search phrase. My question is, what causes this "found"/"not found" in google and how can I avoid it. The site is somewhat SE optimized using google webmaster tools.

Would it be best on Stack Overflow, Super User or Server Fault?

Comment: Remember that if you ever have any questions about how to use the other sites, come ask it here as you have or search: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions about how the Google algorithm work really doesn't fit into any of the Stack Overflow sites ([SOFU for short](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5924/whats-a-good-way-to-refer-to-all-four-sites-collectively)) as it's not the target audience or field of capture for the family of sites.

Your comment:

> Well i am developper and webmaster for that site. It was made for a customer. The customer asks me now, why -- while searching for the same phrase -- one day, his site is listed top 1 or 2, but the other day it is not listed at all. But if he searches for a slightly different phrase (namely plural instead of singular), the website is found and listed top 5. Then, after a few days, the site is back number 1 with the original search phrase. My question is, what causes this "found"/"not found" in google and how can I avoid it. The site is somewhat SE optimized using google webmaster tools.

#### Stack Overflow

Won't fit here as it's not a programming question. You would need to ask it in a way of how you would create an algorithm like Google has if you were to ask the question at SO.

#### Server Fault

Won't fit here as it's not about servers or system admin. For it to be, the question might have to be asked like you wanting to work out how to do some load balancing across the servers that are being queried by millions per second. But right now, it would not fit here.

#### Super User

Won't fit here as it's not a computer question. Unless it was about prefences or something other than how your site is returned.

Comment: Surely it wasn't that blatant was it?

Comment: Not blatant? My ears are still ringing and it's one hour ago!

Answer (score 6):

The Stack Exchange network has grown a lot since this was originally posted, and there is now Webmasters SE, and they have a [pagerank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagerank?sort=frequent&pageSize=15) tag. If this is still an issue, try asking over there. :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, from what angle are you asking? As a developer? As a web-master? Or as a user?

If the question isn't *directly related* to one of these roles... perhaps preview the actual question here so we can make a sensible statement.

Comment: Sounds like a question about SEO

Comment: Well i am developper and webmaster for that site. It was made for a customer.

The customer asks me now, why -- while searching for the same phrase -- one day, his site is listed top 1 or 2, but the other day it is not listed at all. But if he searches for a slightly different phrase (namely plural instead of singular), the website is found and listed top 5.

Then, after a few days, the site is back number 1 with the original search phrase.

My question is, what causes this "found"/"not found" in google and how can I avoid it.

The site is somewhat SE optimized using google webmaster tools.

Comment: Definitely a question about SEO/SERPs. None of SOFU then.

Comment: Sorry, what is SOFU? And have we an appropriate place for my question?

Comment: @Martin: SO: Stack Overflow, SU: Super User, SF: Server Fault -> SOFU

Answer (score 2):

Google have changed their algorithm over the years several times. Rather than focusing merely on it, you might want to learn about **SEO**. Questions about *Search Engine Optimization* (SEO) might be asked in [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com). This site was launched in 2010.

From their *tour*

> Webmasters is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast webmasters.

[seo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo) has +10k questions

> Search Engine Optimization (SEO) is the process of improving the visibility of web content in search engines using an understanding of search engines' processes and algorithms. Also known as "natural" or "organic" search, it is distinct from paid web advertising.

[google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) has +3k questions

> Google Inc. is an American multinational public corporation invested in Internet search, cloud computing, and advertising technologies.

[google-search](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search) has +1k questions

> Google's Search Engine

[pagerank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagerank) (mentioned in a previous answer) has 53 questions

> An algorithm used by Google to determine the placement of webpages in Google search results.

### Related

- [Pro Webmasters](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters) (Area 51 proposal)

Answer (score -3):

In case you're curious, the answer is because Google uses secret sauce. That secret saucing process reshuffles everything fairly regularly.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @acarlstein FYI this "answer" predates the addition of "comments" in the StackOverflow Beta release. I don't mind if you flag it to moderators or whatever you like to do to prune things. Frankly, is this meta questions at all still relevant?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @acarlstein I believe that page was added some 3.25 years after I wrote the above. It's fine, earn and use the option to delete the answer if it's so wrong to you. https://web.archive.org/web/20130616173740/https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer