# Which site answers questions on Google services?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

Which SE site should I ask questions about Google services, especially Gmail?

Comment: Nowadays Google services are too many. There are services for consumers, for groups, busines, enterprises, developers. Documentation entry point are diverse too: https://support.google.com, https://developers.google.com, https://cloud.google.com, just to mention some of them. Related: [Where can I ask general questions about a multi-platform app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/373040/289691)

Comment: Related: [Where can I ask questions about Google (search) ranking/list order?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22112/289691)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're asking about the Web application aspect of a Google service, most likely you're going to want [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). See, for instance, [questions tagged [gmail]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail).

There are some exceptions, however.

- Google Analytics is better on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) ([[google-analytics]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics))
- Search Engine Optimization also belongs on Webmasters ([[seo]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo))
- Google Drive file sync goes on [Super User](http://superuser.com) ([[google-drive]](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive))
- Google also has a smattering of native (non-Web) apps, like Picasa. Questions about them would also go on Super User (e.g., [[picasa]](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/picasa))
- Smartphone apps go on their respective sites: [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com), [Ask Different (Apple)](http://apple.stackexchange.com), [Windows Phone](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com)

Comment: According to the tag excerpt of [google-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) in Super User, this tag is for a deprecated desktop client:`For questions specifically about the now-depreciated computer client for the file synchronization and cloud storage service from Google. This tag should not be used if your question is about Google Backup and Sync or Google Drive File Stream.`. For further details see [What to do with \[google-drive\] and \[google-drive-file-stream\]](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14902/152004). The Windows Phone site was archived.

Comment: Gmail is a complex service. For one side is an email service offering IMAP /POP3 / SMTP protocols, it is a cross-platform app, its a service for email administratrors, can be used by programmers / developers, etc. Questions about using the Web app *might* be on-topic in [webapps.se].