# What is the best site on Stack Exchange to ask about Google's search algorithms (besides Web applications)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am looking for a site on Stack Exchange in which I can ask questions about Google's algorithm.

I am interested in knowing what makes a Google search result (website, link, photo, video, news article, etc.) more prominent or less prominent in a search, and what "Online Reputation Management" websites use in order to "suppress" certain results and make them less prominent in the search.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the question you want to ask? The nuances of your question could mean the sites we recommend could vary.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in knowing what makes a Google search result (website, link, photo, video, news article, etc.) more prominent or less prominent in a search, and what "Online Reputation Management" websites use in order to "suppress" certain results and make them less prominent in the search. thanks.

Comment: The duplicate question currently doesn't answer this question (webmasters is not included in the answer). Someone would have to edit it in first.

Comment: Related: [Where can I ask questions about Google (search) ranking/list order?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22112/289691) from 2009 with answers from 2014 and 2023 :)

Answer (score 3):

[ProWebmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) has over 2900 results for the tag [google-analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics), 750 results for [googlebot](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/googlebot), almost 470 for [google-index](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-index), over 190 results for **[google-ranking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-ranking)**, and over 1600 results for [google-search](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search), etc. SEO is [on-topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Tag Usage:

- Google Analytics is a free web analytics solution provided by Google, featuring several client-side APIs, as well as REST APIs for Data Export and for Management.
- Googlebot is the bot software that Google uses to crawl over 20 billion pages each day, the data obtained during a crawl is then analyzed and ranked on Google Search.
- Google Index is for all web resources crawled by Google bots and recorded in Google databases.
- **Google rankings** is the position of a web site or a web page in Google results.
- The tag excerpt for google-search is not filled out, check other earliest questions to learn when it's best to apply it.

Google's [custom search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element) has a help page available.