# How about a "discussion" checkbox for StackOverflow and SuperUser?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, superuser

I think a good approach to allow have discussions on SO and SU would be have a "discussion" checkbox, like we have the "community wiki" one. Discussions could appear separated from Questions, and would not have the "accept answer" button. That would be really good!

Comment: Why only Stack Overflow and Super User?

Comment: As a Q&A site, SO rocks. As a discussion tool, it's no better, and in some ways *worse*, than plain ol' flat forums like PHPBB. Ever try following a conversation on SO, where the thread is split over several answers with a few dozen comments each? It's brutal...

Comment: @ccomet if there's more, so to them too..

Comment: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) is the other; they're typically referred to as [the trilogy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5924)

Answer (score 11):

Stack Overflow and Super User are not discussion forums, they are Q&A sites.  Having the checkbox would only encourage people to post the kinds of "questions" they are not supposed to be posting in the first place.

If the team wants to start officially admitting discussion questions, to change the overall mission/vision of the site, then make that explicit in the FAQ and just change the Community Wiki checkbox to say Discussion, because that's basically how people are using it (or attempting to use it) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I actually agree that we should add a "Discussion" button to questions.

Clicking the button should immediately delete the question and should then display a FAQ page indicating the difference between a Q&A site, like SO, and a discussion forum!

Answer (score -2):

You, sir, must be in management.

[image: The short answer, as they say, is "no."]